# Unique properties of SwiftData Models when using CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit, swift-data

Unfortunately the `.unique` attribute is not available for SwiftData model properties when using CloudKit.
Is there a best practice to setup a constraint like this for my own models?

For the local DB it's rather straight forward to fetch (and filter) the models before creating & inserting a new one.

But how can the duplication of models from other devices be prevented - i.e. merge duplicated models with locally existing ones before inserting them into the local SwiftData DB on imports from CloudKit?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, having unique properties in CloudKit is not possible.
According to the Apple's docs:

```
@Attribute - The framework synchronizes changes concurrently and at opportune times, which means CloudKit is unable to enforce the unique property option.
```

I would suggest to manually delete the duplicates on every device. You can deal with it by creating a background task scheduler, which would be responsible for deleting entities from your database. This isn't the perfect solution, but it should be working. Anyway you will have to deal with conflict in UI with your duplicates. It depends only on you how to solve it. For instance: Show the most recent data, or show an error ... etc