# SwiftData: How to detect when CloudKit synced (or is about to sync) new data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift-data

Two things:

- How do I detect when SwiftData with CloudKit finished syncing new data from somewhere else?
- How do I detect if there are changes that still need to be synced?

Some background:
There currently seems to be [no way to avoid duplicates in SwiftData with CloudKit enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586527/unique-properties-of-swiftdata-models-when-using-cloudkit) and apparently the only way is to manually remove duplicates.

"Ideally", I'd like to do that after the CloudKit sync completed. And/or avoid fetching new data before CloudKit finished syncing in the first place when starting the App.

Comment: I think you want to look into `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` notifications

Comment: I'm also searching for a way to do this. From my tests, `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` doesn't work for this situation, but I could be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Afaict there's no way to properly do this and no straightforward way to detect if something has actually been synced or is about to sync (other than maybe listening for CoreData changes and trying to rule out those changes which sounds like a nightmare).

What I did get somewhat working is a way to delay the refresh after the App starts until the initial iCloud sync has finished, which hopefully avoids the main cause of creating duplicates.

```
@Observable class RefreshManager {
    
    @MainActor var isSyncing: Bool = false
    @ObservationIgnored var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    @ObservationIgnored var syncDoneTask: Task<(), Never>?
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification)
            .sink { [weak self] notification in
                guard let self else { return }
                
                if let event = notification.userInfo?[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventNotificationUserInfoKey]
                    as? NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.Event {
                    
                    syncDoneTask?.cancel()
                    if event.endDate == nil {
                        // starting some sync event
                        
                        Task { @MainActor in
                            self.isSyncing = true
                        }

                    } else {
                        // event done
                        syncDoneTask = Task {
                            do {
                                // Wait for no more sync events to show up
                                try await Task.sleep(s: 3)
                                await self.handleIcloudSyncDone()
                            } catch {
                                // task cancelled
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancelSyncListener()
    }
    
    func cancelSyncListener() {
        cancellables.removeAll()
    }
    
    func handleIcloudSyncDone() async {
        Task { @MainActor in
            self. isSyncing = false
        }
        
        // Make sure this function is not called repeatedly for future updates
        cancelSyncListener()
        
        // do something after sync is done
    }
}
```